# Использование повторного cin в блоке catch

Tags: исключения, c++

Доброго времени, нужно сделать так, что если ввод с ошибкой, предложить чтение еще раз с помощью блока try / catch. Написал такой код, но повторно считать не дает. Думаю, возможно, в потоке остается старый некорректный символ. Пробовал очищать поток ввода, но результата не дало. Как можно разрешить данную проблему?

```
try {
    cin >> r;
} catch(istream::failure e)
{
    cout << "Oh, you entered bad value! Try again: ";
    try {
        cin >> r;
    } catch(istream::failure e)
    {
        cout << "As I can see, you not very smart, so bye bye!" << endl;
        return 0;
    };
};
```

Comment: @skad0, можно, например, прочесть строку до конца и выбросить ее содержимое. Зависит от Вашей задачи в целом.

Да, и зачем здесь try/catch?

Comment: Вы не должны предполагать, что пользователь введёт значение правильно => try/catch не нужен. Читайте строку, пробуйте распарсить значение из неё (istringstream вам в помощь), при ошибке повторяйте.

Comment: Это учебный пример, такова постановка задачи. Я очищал с помщью cin.clear() и не удавалось.

Comment: @skad0, а Вы документацию читали?

    void clear (iostate state = goodbit);
    Set error state flags
    Sets a new value for the stream's internal error state flags.

видите, ничего про изменения байтиков в потоке не пишут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, еще один блок try внутри catch - идея так себе. Внутри этого блока понадобится еще один, затем еще один. Проще сделать так:

```
bool needRestart = true;

while(needRestart)
{
    try {
        ... // логика, которая может сгенерировать исключение         
        needRestart = false;
    } 
    catch(istream::failure e)
    {
        cout << "Oh, you entered bad value! Try again: ";
        needRestart = true;
    };
}
```

Comment: Возможно, стоить ещё сбросить буфер: http://stackoverflow.com/a/257182/276994

Comment: Спасибо, это, конечно, не совсем по заданию, но этот вариант лучше.